# How to recognize float variable? getting ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python, string, floating-point, valueerror

I'm trying to create a GUI for a signal analysis simulation that i'm writing in Python. For that, I use AppJar. However, when I call the function that generates the signal, I get a ValueError like in the title.

I've read every single ValueError post on stackOverflow (i could have missed one maybe, but i did my best) and all of them are about extra spacings, letters that can not be parsed as a floating point number, etc. None of that seems to apply here.

Basically, i'm using this code to call a function to generate my signal:

```
signal_axes = app.addPlot("signal", *logic.signal(5, 2), 0, 0, 1)
```

And the relevant part of the function itself (in the file logic.py, which is imported)

```py
def signal(electrodes, length):
   velocity = math.sqrt((3.2e-19 * kinetic_energy) / (mass * 1.66e-27))
   frequency = velocity / length
```

This is not the whole function, the variables are all declared and unused variables are used later in the function.

The error specifically points to the line with "frequency = velocity / length", telling me:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'str'
```

When i try to fix it by using "float(length)" i get the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

In one of the answers on StackExchange someone suggested using .strip() to get rid of invisible spaces. So i tried using:

```
length.strip()
```

But that gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

I am slowly descending into madness here. The following code, by the way, stand-alone, works:

```py
import numpy as np

kinetic_energy = 9000
mass = 40
length = 2e-2

velocity = np.sqrt((3.2e-19 * kinetic_energy) / (mass * 1.66e-27))
frequency = float(velocity) / float(length)

print(frequency)
```

Can anyone see what could be wrong? I've included all the relevant code below, it's not my complete file but this alone should give an output, at least.

*run.py*

```py
import logic
from appjar import gui

def generate(btn):
    app.updatePlot("signal", *logic.signal(app.getEntry("electrodes"), app.getEntry("length")))
    showSignalLabels()

def showSignalLabels():
    signal_axes.set_xlabel("time (us)")
    signal_axes.set_ylabel("amplitude (uV)")
    app.refreshPlot("signal")

app = gui()

signal_axes = app.addPlot("signal", *logic.signal(5, 0.02), 0, 0, 1)


app.addLabelEntry("electrodes", 1, 0, 1)
app.addLabelEntry("length", 2, 0, 1)

showSignalLabels()

app.addButton("Generate", generate)
app.go()
```

*logic.py*

```py
import numpy as np
import math
import colorednoise as cn


steps = 5000
amplitude = 1
offset_code = 0
kinetic_energy = 9000
mass = 40
centered = 1


def signal(electrodes, length):
    velocity = math.sqrt((3.2e-19 * kinetic_energy) / (mass * 1.66e-27))
    frequency = velocity / length
    time = 2 * (electrodes / frequency)

    --- irrelevant code ---

    return OutputTime, OutputSignal
```

edit: here is the full traceback.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Internship IOM\WPy64-3720\python-3.7.2.amd64\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:\Internship IOM\PythonScripts\appJar\appjar.py", line 3783, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: funcName(param)
  File "E:/Internship IOM/PythonScripts/appJar/testrun.py", line 12, in generate
    app.updatePlot("signal", *logic.signal(app.getEntry("electrodes"), app.getEntry("length")))
  File "E:\Internship IOM\PythonScripts\appJar\logic.py", line 33, in signal
    frequency = velocity / length
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'str'
```

Comment: The full traceback would let us see which caller of `signal` is passing `length` as a string, please can you provide that?

Comment: Hmm, usually the value error "Could not convert string to float: " will have the value it's trying to convert after the colon. This makes me think there's some error with the value of length being passed. Can you confirm that the length value passed in is correct with a simple print statement?

Comment: a_guest's answer provided me with a solution already, thank you! I've included the traceback anyway, for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert at the calling site, i.e. do:

```
def generate(btn):
    app.updatePlot("signal", *logic.signal(app.getEntry("electrodes"),
                                           float(app.getEntry("length"))))
    ...
```

Because otherwise your function `logic.signal` receives different type (`str` and `float`). That's why you receive the other error about `float` has no `strip` because somewhere else in your code you do:

```
signal_axes = app.addPlot("signal", *logic.signal(5, 0.02), 0, 0, 1)
```

Here you pass it a `float`.

Since your original error was `could not convert string to float` with an apparently empty string, you need to take an extra measure to prevent empty values from the app. You can use a `try ... except`:

```
def generate(btn):
    try:
        length = float(app.getEntry("length"))
    except ValueError:
        # Use some default value here, or re-raise.
        length = 0.
    app.updatePlot("signal", *logic.signal(app.getEntry("electrodes"), length))
```

Comment: that solved it! thank you. One more thing for people who read this in the future: I noticed that when i tested the script, I left the second entry field (length) empty. I only gave a value for the field (electrodes). Passing an empty field may have confused the function as well.